Mini junction box
Our designer picked out a picture light, but when it showed up the base plate for the picture light is only 1 3/4 x 4.5”. That means if I install it on the smallest box that I can think of, a handy box, they’ll still be 1/16-1/8” of the handy box exposed underneath the cover plate. I’ve seen mini junction boxes, but the screw patterns aren’t midline so they wouldn’t fit the mounting plate. I contacted the manufacturer and they suggested using additional drywall to narrow the opening which I’m pretty sure violates Electrical code having drywall in the box.
Has anybody run across this? How do you install these?
—-
Thanks everyone – it is UL certified. The supplier didn’t have any additional hardware or junction boxes, Or advice. 
I did find this mini box on Amazon ($15…) but the holes aren’t right. I suppose I could mount my light to the box cover and put a hole through the cover to bring the wires through. I also doubt the cubic inches are even enough for the wires but that’s a more minor issue.


First check the light is UL(or ETL/CSA) listed(if in NA).  If not listed, have designer take it back.  CE label is not recognized in North America.

A picture of the mounting part of the light would be helpful in answering this. One option would be a junction box cover under it, with a hole to pass wiring into it, but I can't be sure there isn't some reason that won't work without knowing what it actually looks like.

The opening of a 1-gang mud ring seems promising but it's also about 1/8 too wide.  If you bought it at an architectural supply, they probably have the necessary parts for it.  If you bought it on Ali Express or whatever, it may not be suitable for mounting in North America.  In some countries you can just poke NM through a hole in the plaster.

Edited original post
